# Python Get Base64 Encoded Byte String as a String of Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

Given the python code

```
import base64
byte = base64.b64encode(b'hello')
```

`byte` has the value

```
b'aGVsbG8='
```

But I'm trying to get the string of the literal encoded bytes inside the `b'`...`'` notation.

Only solution I've found so far is to cast the bytes as string and get the substring of the value without the first two and last characters,

```
str(byte)[2:-1]
```

which gives me

```
'aGVsbG8='
```

While this works, it feels like a complete hack.

Comment: `byte.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Perhaps it's worth tagging this question with `python3`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one also works:

```
str(byte, 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Decode it as ASCII:

```
byte.decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Just using `decode()` would probably work as well...